# Raku: One line expression to capture group from string?

Tags: string, raku

I am capturing a number from a string thus:

```
my $n1;
if $string1 ~~ /(<[0..4]>)$/ {
    $n1 = $0;
} else {
    put "$string1 failed regex.";
    die;
}
```

which is a lot of lines, but I can copy and edit strings in a single line thus:

```
my $string2 = $group2.subst(/<[0..4]>$/, '');
```

I'm still learning raku/perl6, and I've looked through https://docs.perl6.org/type/Str and it doesn't look like Raku can do this... but I'm not sure.

is there a way that I can capture a substring in a single line, similar to the first code sample above?

I do this process repeatedly in my scripts, and it would really shorten my scripts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe [.match](https://docs.raku.org/type/Str#method_match) is what you are looking for.

```
my $string1='4';
my $n2 = $string1.match(/(<[0..4]>)$/) // die 'error';
say $n2.values;
```

Answer (score 14):

It is possible to use a destructuring bind to extract parts of a match into variables. For the example given, we can extract the matched part like this:

```
my ($n) := "abc123" ~~ /(<[1..4]>+)$/;
say $n;  # ｢123｣
```

This scales up to extracting multiple parts of the match:

```
my ($s, $n) := "abc123" ~~ /(<[a..z]>+)(<[1..4]>+)$/;
say $s;  # ｢abc｣
say $n;  # ｢123｣
```

Captured things in Raku are themselves `Match` objects, but it's possible to use coercion in the destructuring too, in order to turn it into an integer:

```
my (Int() $n) := "abc123" ~~ /(<[1..4]>+)$/;
say $n;       # 123
say $n.WHAT;  # (Int)
```

It even works with named matches (a bit artificial here, but handy if you are making subrule calls):

```
my (:$s, :$n) := "abc123" ~~ /$<s>=(<[a..z]>+) $<n>=(<[1..4]>+)$/;
say $s;  # ｢abc｣
say $n;  # ｢123｣
```

The obvious downside of this is that one can get an exception if it fails to match. Thankfully, however, this can be combined with an `if`:

```
if "abc123" ~~ /(<[a..z]>+)(<[1..4]>+)$/ -> ($s, $n) {
    say $s;
    say $n;
}
```

And the same syntax works, because a destructuring bind is actually just an application of signatures.

Comment: Smalltalk would be proud.  Especially with that named matches example.  Not that I know much about smalltalk..